# Connection string hidden somewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two databases on one machine that also has two different sites running on IIS. Lets call them Site1 & Site2 and DB1 & DB2. The second site and BD are copys of the first one. The Site2 connects to DB2 and everything seems to work nice but when we **took offline the DB1** it stoped working which is wierd since all the data created using the site2 was in DB2. In fact most of the site works except for one method

We use entity framework to access the database and when we trace the code everything looks ok, but it somehow doesn't work.

In our auto-generated code by entity framework we traced the connectiong string and the outcome is correct

```
Initial Catalog=DB2;
```

But in the next line we have this code

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<T_REFERENCE_DATA>(
                "GetReferenceData", groupNameParameter);
```

And we get an inner exception that says:

```
Database 'DB1' cannot be opened because it is offline.
```

All the other methods seem to use the correct database except this one. We can't figure out where the DB1 is configured or hardcoded

Comment: is there anything in Global.asax?  or in a web.config or app.config?

Comment: You could also try lookin in the `~/Properties/Settings.settings` file

Comment: Places i know people store connection strings is in web/app/machine .config files.

Comment: @Brian - Global doesn't have anything, web.config has the correct config and the specific project of the data entity doesn't have app.settings

Comment: @Jupaol Properties doesn't have that file

Comment: @Tony318 I don't know where that is.

The big difficulty with this bug is that all the other methods seem to work just fine. Why would only one method use this DB?

Comment: Machine Config is C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\vx.x\machine.config  the vx.x is whatever framework you are using be it 2.0 3.5 or 4.0. Its possible that one of the methods you are using is trying to make a connection to that DB. You can try removing that connection string for DB1 since it is offline and you may want to step through that method and make sure it doesn't try and do anything with DB1.

Comment: Found that file here C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
No mention on any of the DBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was (as usual) stupid as hell. Some of the guys defined the DB on the stored procedures. When we changed DB and copied the stored procedures they kept using the old DB. It is now fixed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I've been an idiot too, and encountered exactly the same issue.  Even thought I'd checked the Stored Procedure twice (in my instance), I did not notice the database name hidden away.